# Redshift Unload with case-sensitive headers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Previously, unload command did not create header row. This functionality is now available with "HEADER" option. However, it does not preserve the case of the headers.

The following statement creates a file with header "my column header 1"...

```
UNLOAD ('SELECT col1 "My Column Header 1", col2 "My Column Header 2" FROM mytable;')  
TO 's3://mybucket/filename.csv.'  
CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=mycredentials'  
DELIMITER ','  
HEADER  
ALLOWOVERWRITE 
ADDQUOTES  
PARALLEL OFF;
```

Is there a way to preserve case in column headings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way to do that when using the HEADER option, because Redshift does not have case sensitive column names. All identifiers (table names, column names etc.) are always stored in **lower case** in the Redshift metadata.

You can optionally set a parameter so that column names are all returned as upper case *in the results of a SELECT statement*.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_names.html

> ASCII letters in standard and delimited identifiers are case-insensitive and are folded to lowercase in the database. In query results, column names are returned as lowercase by default. To return column names in uppercase, set the describe_field_name_in_uppercase configuration parameter to true.

Comment: Check the answer by @rajish-sani combined with the comment from user schiavuzzi. THAT is the real answer, not this one.

Comment: @Henrov  This was the correct answer when this question was asked four years ago. It appears that Redshift has had an option added to allow case sensitive identifiers at some point since then.

Comment: I understand. That is why I thought it necessary to make that comment, to direct people having the same issue (me) towards the now proper solution.

Answer (score 3):

Modify the Redshift server configuration using SET property

enable_case_sensitive_identifier - A configuration value that determines whether name identifiers of databases, tables, and columns are case sensitive

```
SET enable_case_sensitive_identifier TO true;
SELECT or CREATE TABLE
RESET enable_case_sensitive_identifier;
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Modifying_the_default_settings.html

Comment: This worked for me. Note, you also need to enclose your column names in the SQL query's SELECT clause within double quotes for this to work. Unquoted column names will still be converted to lowercase. Check the AWS docs above.

Comment: This is the actual answer

Comment: An important remark is that these changes impact only your session. From my understanding it should be safe to use in production without fear of impacting other users.

> using a SET command to override a setting for the duration of the current session only

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm_chap_ConfigurationRef.html